# Swift UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads?

Tags: swift

There was a problem when I declared a variable.
This is my situation.

```
        let att = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L0Ua.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to post the code not image.

Comment: also, check you have implement right init method `init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double)`

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I have added the code

Comment: Again you have to post the code which you had tried, your problem is not in the code means image and code are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at an old example from Swift 2.  This method has been renamed as of Swift 3 as part of the [grand renaming](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/06/swift-3/):

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutattributes/1617759-init)